# Daily workflow management using Quartz

Tags: workflow, quartz-scheduler, scheduling, osworkflow

I want to execute a workflow on a daily basis. The workflow for today will not start until the workflow for the previous day is complete. The workflow for a day has a bunch of tasks that execute in parallel at different timings (crons). Once these tasks are completed successfully, there are another set of tasks that can be executed in parallel. Once the second set of tasks are complete, the workflow is said to be completed for the day. I am wondering how I can model this workflow. For managing crons, I thought I will use Quartz but however for managing the workflow, I am not sure how to go about it. I did look at osworkflow that is supposed to work very well with Quartz but I am not able to come to a good design.

Thanks,

Venkat